# Django throwing attribute error and i dont know why it is happening

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to take image input from user in Django first the code was working fine but when I tried to run this code after a week it is giving me an attribute error and I don't why it is happening I tried to search on the internet but they only say it is because of the wrong syntax. The line, where the error arises, is  `file_type = file_type.lower()` and line will be at last in the product_details function

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from datetime import datetime
from machine_website.models import contact_detail
from machine_website.models import product_data
from machine_website.forms import product_Form


# Create your views here.

def homepage(request):
    descp1 = product_data()
    descp1.disc = ' this is the discription'
    descp1.img = '2.jpg'

    descp2 = product_data()
    descp2.disc = ' this is the discription 2'
    descp2.img = '2.jpg'

    descp3 = product_data()
    descp3.disc = ' this is the discription 3'
    descp3.img = '5.jpg'

    descp = [descp1, descp2,descp3]
    return render(request,'homepage.html', {'descp': descp})

def contact(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
      name = request.POST.get('name')
      email = request.POST.get('email')
      desc = request.POST.get('desc')
      contact = contact_detail(name=name , email=email, desc=desc, date=datetime.today())
      contact.save()
    return render(request,'contact.html')

def services(request):
    return render(request,'services.html')

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("this is index page")


def more(request):

    info = product_data.objects.all()

    return render(request ,'more.html' , {'info' : info})

IMAGE_FILE_TYPES = ['png' , 'PNG' , 'jpg' , 'JPG' , 'jpeg' , 'jfif']

def product_details(request):
    form = product_Form()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = product_Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user_pr = form.save(commit=False)
            user_pr.img = request.FILES['img']
            file_type = user_pr.img.url.split('.')
            file_type = file_type.lower()
            if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
               return render(request, 'error.html')
            user_pr.save()
            return render(request, 'details.html', {'user_pr': user_pr})
    context = {"form": form,}
    return render(request, 'product_details.html', context)
```

**TRACEBACk CALL**

```
 File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\naveen\Desktop\cpp programs\first django project\machine_website\views.py", line 59, in product_details
    file_type = file_type.lower()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
[17/Apr/2021 17:00:46] "POST /product_details/ HTTP/1.1" 500 67315
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the error traceback?

Comment: `file_type = user_pr.img.url.split('.')` this implies `file_type` is a list yet you call `file_type.lower()`, this would obviously give an error.